# Does code alignment make a difference in compiler output?

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction

Let's say I got some code written in C++ and I compile it with gcc.
Now let's say I push everything in one line and compile it again.
Does the output bytes of the compiler change?
If so, what changes and why?

Comment: You could just try it out, although I'd be surprised if anything would change

Comment: With "pushing in one line", do you mean removing all newlines and leaving the rest the same? If so, no.

Comment: Depends on the code.  Some code may include date or time stamps; thus the code will change between compilations.

Comment: What kind of "difference" do you consider to be a difference?  The lines numbers are different.  The object code could be different every time you compile, even if you don't change anything (e.g., date/time stamp, anonymous namespace anonymizer).

Comment: You mean indentation / whitespace in the source?  From the title, I thought it was going to be about memory alignment of the machine code, like `gcc -falign-functions=4` https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: Try it. See what happens.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the output bytes of the compiler change?

Compilers may produce information that maps produced assembly instructions to lines of the original source code. This may be called "debug information". In case the compiler produces debug information, that information will be different if you change the line numbers or file names etc.

Then there is the macro `__LINE__` and the newish `std::source_location::line` which will even change the meaning of the source code and thus may change the compiler output.

Comment: That `__LINE__` macro and a few of its friends were an absolute <expletive deleted> one time when I had to prove two versions of code produced identical binaries.